# What is the free version of Sharepoint and where do I get it?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2003, wss

For (quite literally) playing around at home, I'd like to get a copy of Sharepoint.  I might find a use for it, so I don't want a trial version.  I'm aware that there is a "free" version that doesn't include the MS Office integration etc, and that's fine.  I just might use it for document storage and things.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your after [Windows Sharepoint Services](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_SharePoint_Services), WSS for short, as opposed to [MOSS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Office_SharePoint_Server) which isn't free.  It's available for Windows Server 2003 and 2008. Should come pre-installed with Windows Server 2003 R2, or you can download it [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/sharepoint/bb400747.aspx)
Details for downloading/installing on 2008 is [here.](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287813.aspx)

Don't think it's possible to run it on a client OS like Windows XP or Windows 7, so if you dont have this running at home, you'll have to get something like Virtual PC or VMWare and something like an MSDN or technet licence.

Comment: For SharePoint 2010, WSS is now SharePoint Foundation.

Answer (score 1):

Youcan install WSS 3.0 on a Windows 7 box. It does require you to modify the local machine gpo. You can find information regarding that [Here.](http://community.bamboosolutions.com/blogs/bambooteamblog/archive/2009/05/07/installing-wss-3-0-moss-sp2-on-windows-7-rc.aspx)
And as far as sql goes you can use sql server express.